# Using 'to bridge' in a temporal context

Tags: word-usage

I'm a non-native speaker.

Amongst others, Merriam-Webster defines the noun 'Bridge' as follows:

> a time, place, or means of connection or transition building a bridge between the two cultures the bridge from war to peace

If I were to use the verb 'to bridge' in a temporal context, e.g

> He could bridge the waiting time by solving puzzles

would that sound natural to native speakers?

Comment: No, that does not sound natural. You would *pass the time,*; but a certain custom might "bridge the centuries."

Comment: These [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bridge+the+waiting+time+by%2Cbridge+the+time+by&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=) back up Dave's judgement (and mine).

Comment: It doesn't work because it is focusing on the wrong thing. This idiom focuses on the two sides, not the gulf in between.

Comment: Sprottenwels, could you go back and edit your Question to use what Merriam-Webster actually said, including all the punctuation?

Either way no, *He could bridge the waiting time by solving puzzles* would not sound natural. What's normally use in that situation is not *bridge* but *… fill the time…*

Comment: to bridge a gap between two things, is the bottom line.